# Cargar productos de forma dinamica a Chekout pro de MercadoPago

Tags: php, mercadopago

Llevo varias horas buscando una solución y nada.
El problema es que me carga solo el ultimo elemento de mi carrito guardado en mi variable de seción "CARRITO".
De forma no dinamica los productos se cargarian mediante el array `$preference->items = $array($item1,$item2...);`  separado por comas.

Lo que estoy haciendo es que en cada iteración del `foreach` creo una variable dinámica `$nombre_de_variable`, en cada iteración tiene un nombre distinto (`$item1,$item2...`), se van cargando con los datos extraidos de mi varible de seción y al finalizar se cargarián los datos al array.

```
$numItem = 0;
$arrayItems = array();

foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice=>$producto) {
    // Define variables
    $nombre_de_variable = "item"."$numItem";

    $NOMBRE = $producto['NOMBRE'];
    $PRECIO = $producto['PRECIO'];
    $CANTIDAD = $producto['CANTIDAD'];
    
    // Crea un ítem en la preferencia
    $nombre_de_variable = new MercadoPago\Item();
    $nombre_de_variable->title = "$NOMBRE";
    $nombre_de_variable->quantity = $CANTIDAD;
    $nombre_de_variable->unit_price = $PRECIO;
    $nombre_de_variable->currency_id = "UYU";

    $arrayItems=array($nombre_de_variable);

    $numItem++;
}

$preference->items = $arrayItems;
$preference->save();
...
```

Comment: No he usado esa API nunca pero se ve raro que, al final, le asignas a `$preference->items` el contenido de `$arrayItems` y en la siguiente instrucción, sobreescribes eso con un array vacío.

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, definitivamente es un error que tuve al copiar el código, gracias por la observación, de igual modo el comportamiento es el que explique en la pregunta. El array queda solo con el registro del último elemento insertado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto que has puesto a continuación estas sobreescribiendo (que no agregando nada) la variable `@arrayItems` en cada iteración:

```
$arrayItems = array($nombre_de_variable);
```

Lo que supongo que pretendes es más bien esto:

```
$arrayItems[] = $nombre_de_variable;
```

De esta forma la variable `$arrayItems` almacenará un nuevo elemento de array en cada iteración.

Comment: Definitivamente era ese el error, al cambiar ```$arrayItems = array($nombre_de_variable```por ```$arrayItems[] = $nombre_de_variable;``` quedó funcionando a la perfección. Muchas gracias!